# understanding phrasing of taylor polynomial question

Tags: calculus, polynomials, taylor-expansion

Show that $|\sin x - x + \frac{1}{6}x^3| < 0.08$ for $|x| \le \frac{\pi}2$. How large do you have to take $k$ so that the $k$th order Taylor polynomial of $ \sin x$ about $a=0 $ approximates $\sin x$ to within $0.01$ for $|x|\le \frac{\pi}2$?

My question has to do with how to interpret the $|x| \le\frac{\pi}2$ part. The Taylor polynomial can be about any number, in other words it doesn't have to be around $0$ like in this question, so that would mean the interval $|x| \le\frac{ \pi}2$ may not correspond to where the Taylor polynomial is. Or is it implying a distance of $\frac{\pi}2$ away from wherever my Taylor polynomial is approximating around?

Answer (score 0):

The Taylor series is specified as being expanded about the point $x=0$ (called the *center* of the series. By asking to you approximate $\sin x$ with its third order Taylor polynomial (about $x=0$) **on the interval** $|x|\le \pi/2$, you are being told the interval on which to apply [Taylor's Remainder Theorem](http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Early%20Transcendentals/upfiles/Formulas4RemainderTaylorSeries5ET.pdf).

Suppose $f(x)$ has Taylor series centered at $x=a$ given by $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(x-a)^n, \quad\text{where }c_n={f^{(n)}(a)\over n!},$$ and let
$$
R_N(x):=f(x)-\sum_{n=0}^N c_n(x-a)^n
$$
denote the remainder or error between $f(x)$ and the first $N$ terms of its Taylor series. Then we have:

> **Lagrange's Form of the Remainder:** If $f^{(N+1)}$ is continuous on an open interval $I$ that contains $a$, and $x$ is in $I$, then there
>   exists a number $c$ between $a$ and $x$ such that
>   $$R_N(x)={f^{(N+1)}(c)\over (N+1)!}(x-a)^{N+1}.$$

So you can see how the interval $I$ (along with the center, $a$) is involved in a discussion of error analysis.

Comment: Shouldn't the interval that i apply the remainder theorem to be the same interval at which the series is centered at? In this case it happens to be that way, but i was working on a prior question and the center of the series was not in the interval requested for the remainder

Comment: "interval at which the series is centered at"? I don't understand: Taylor series are constructed at a point, say $x=x_0$, called the *center* of the series. But it's not an interval. Then, we can compute the interval on which the series converges, called the *interval of convergence*. But they are different things. Look closely at Example 3 in the link provided. I think it will help.

Comment: It did clarify it quite a bit thanks. So the interval of convergence will be where the remainder ends up tending to 0 faster than my x-a term resulting in the taylor series perfectly approximating a function. At this point where the taylor series equals the function is it safe to call it an analytical function?