# Taylor's Theorem For Error Approximation

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to evaluate a function $f(t)$ with a given $t$ value to within 10$^{-5}$.

So, if I use Taylor's Theorem :

$f(a)+f′(a)1!(x−a)+f′′(a)2!(x−a)2+⋯+f(n)(a)n!(x−a)n.$

Would my $t$ value = $a, f(t) = f(a),$ and $ n= 5$? Meaning that I would have to evaluate the 5th derivative of my $f(x)$?

Comment: Use Taylor's Formula to calculate the remainder: $\frac{f^{n+1}(a)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}$

Comment: Study [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1040643/52893) and the examples linked there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

> **Lagrange's Form of the Remainder:** If $f^{(N+1)}$ is continuous on an open interval $I$ that contains $a$, and $x$ is in $I$, then there
>   exists a number $c$ between $a$ and $x$ such that
>   $$R_N(x)={f^{(N+1)}(c)\over (N+1)!}(x-a)^{N+1}.$$

You didn't tell us what your $f(x)$ was or the center of the series, $a$, or the $x$ value at which you want the approximation smaller than $10^{-5}$. But given those ingredients, you find the smallest positive integer $N$ which solves the inequality
$$
|R_N(x)|<10^{-5}.
$$

In practice, you can replace $|f^{(N+1)}(c)|$ with $\max_{x\in I}|f^{(N+1)}(x)|$ since the latter is an upper bound on the former. This will provide an upper bound on $|R_N(x)|$.

Comment: PS If you provide the $f$, $a$, and $x$, I can help you with the specifics.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was simply told to "evaluate" ln(0.8) to within 10^{-5} and I didn't want to give too much of the question away in an attempt to answer it myself. I'm assuming the center is 0 though in this case?

Comment: Well $\ln(0)$ isn't defined so I'd center the Taylor series of $f(x)=\ln x$ at $a=1$ instead (closest integer to $0.8$).

Comment: Ah, of course. I can't believe I said that. Thanks again. Does the center always have to be a whole number?

Comment: Nope, we just tend to be positively biased towards those. ;-)